# Prevent image loading with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading

I am looking in building a simple email client and I am stuck at the point, where the client should ask if the user wants to see images/hide them on spam messages. Any approaches are welcome.

> How to prevent images from loading within a 'container' with angularJS

Please, note:
I am looking for angular solution so please do not suggest jQuery as they do not play nice together. Although pure JS is welcomed

[**'Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work'**](http://xp.c2.com/DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork.html) kind of solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` feature

In controller

```
$scope.toggleImage = false; // true - Show, false - Hide. By default hide image.
```

In View template

```
<img ng-src="" ng-if="toggleImage">
<a href="" ng-click="toggleImage = !toggleImage">Toggle Image</a>
```

Thanks @musically_ut for the correction.

Comment: This will still fetch the images but will just not show them. With an e-mail client, you do not want to even request the images. Use `ng-if` to prevent the _loading_ of images.

Comment: @musically_ut could you provide an answer with example as I am relatively new to Angular and I am not sure how should I use ng-if in a html content (coming from non-angular source)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov Use the solution above but with `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way where you can show picture in angular. All you need to add is a boolean which is true when it's not spam.

Html :

```
<!-- language: html -->
<div ng-app ng:controller="ShowHideController">
    <div ng-repeat='image in images'>
        <img ng-src="{{image}}"/>
    </div>
    <button ng-click='showImage()'> show image </button>
<div>
```

Javascript :

```
    function ShowHideController($scope) {

    $scope.showImage = function(){
        $scope.images = ['https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'];
    }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGA4T/)

Also what you can do is when it's true that its spam . Set the $scope.images to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what OP wants, i think the best way is to use:

```
<img ng-src="{{vm.isVisible ? 'path/to/image' : ''}}" />
```

This prevents the image from being loaded.